# How to work with many database schemas in a laravel migration file?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to separate my tables into different schemas while writing migration files with Laravel.

I was wondering what's the best approach to do it. Currently, the table creation goes like:

```
 Schema::create('schema_name.table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        (...)
    });
```

Should I try to use a different connection, another option or it's ok like this?

Comment: Don't you google it first before posting question?

Comment: yes I did. and I actually know how to do it. But I don't like this approach.
Do you have any contribution besides googling?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

first in **config/database.php** add another connection

```
'connections' => [
    'mysql' => [...],

    'mysql1' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_NAME', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

      ...
]
```

Then in migration

```
Schema::connection('mysql1')->create('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    (...)
});
```

Comment: I added a connection with other schema set. In the Migration class extended by laravel migrations there's a $connection property.

It doesn's seems to change anything if I set my connection there. Do you know how does it works?

Comment: in this answer i added `mysql1` new connection then i changed connection in migration as above then simply run `php artisan migrate` it will migrate. after that in `Model` add `protected $connection = 'mysql1'` and use model as you always do.

Comment: I wish there was a better way... anyway, I think that's the proper answer